Evaluating a residue of the type $e^{iz}$ where $z = e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}$
I was asked to evaluate the integral $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{1+x^4} d x $ using the techniques in complex analysis. (Cauchy's residue theorem)
I constructed a contour and found out there are two simple poles inside the contour (in the top circle) at $z = e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}$ and $z = e^{\frac{3i\pi}{4}}$
I find it hard to evaluate  $e^{e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}}$ to get a value for the resiude. Is there any expression for this?
Because in the final answer i have to separate the imaginary part and the real part of it in order to get a value for the given integral.
I kept $\cos z$ term as it is and evaluated it at $z=e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}$. I got it as $\cos (\frac{1}{\sqrt2} + i \frac{1}{\sqrt2} )$. Then I used the expansion that involves the hyperbolic function and separated it into the imaginary and real parts, but this method seemed too lengthy, nevertheless, I ended up having an answer that differed from the real answer shown in online calculators.
my answer is $\frac{\pi}{2^{\frac{2}{3}}} (cos a \cosh a - \sin a \sinh a) $ where a = $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$
